Equality of induced maps on fundamental groups on torus
Let $T = S^1 \times S^1$ with the basepoint $(1, 1)$. Prove that two based maps $f, g : T \to T$ are homotopic if and only if the maps $f_*, g_* : \pi_1(T) \to \pi_1(T)$ are equal.
Of course, if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic maps, then $f_* = g_*$. I'm stuck with the other direction. Any hints/solutions would be appreciated.

What textbook are you reading and how much algebraic topology do you know?

(Presumably exploiting that $T$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z}^2, 1)$ and representability of ordinary cohomology is too high-tech?)

@MoisheKohan I am primarily using Hatcher, and am familiar with SVK, covering spaces etc.

@BenSteffan That $K$ notation appears to be something I'm unfamiliar with.

Hint: Then lift to the universal covers and think about the straight-line homotopy and its equivaraince.

Given $x\in T$ we may take a path $\phi\colon [0,1] \to T$, with $\phi(0)=(1,1)$ and $\phi(1)=x$, so $\phi$ is a path from the basepoint to $x$.
We have paths $f\circ \phi$ and $g\circ\phi$ in $T$. These may each be lifted uniquely to paths $\phi_f,\phi_g\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ respectively, such that $\phi_f(0)=\phi_g(0)=(0,0)$.
Here we lift with respect to the covering map $p\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \to T$, sending $(x,y)\mapsto (e^{ix},e^{iy})$.  That is $$p\circ \phi_f= f\circ \phi,\qquad p\circ \phi_g= g\circ \phi.$$
Now for $t\in[0,1]$ define $$h_t(x)=p(t\phi_f(1)+(1-t)\phi_g(1)).$$
This will be our desired homotopy.  First we must show it is a well defined function.  That is we must show that it does not depend on choice of path $\phi$.
Let $\phi'$ be another path from $(1,1)$ to $x$.  Then $\phi' \cdot \phi^{-1}\in \pi_1(T,(1,1))$.  Further $$(f\circ \phi') \cdot (f\circ \phi)^{-1}=f_*(\phi' \cdot \phi^{-1})=g_*(\phi' \cdot \phi^{-1})=(g\circ \phi') \cdot (g\circ \phi)^{-1}$$ as elements of $\pi_1(T,(1,1))$.  Let $w$ denote this element, so we have $$f\circ\phi'=w\cdot (f\circ\phi),\qquad g\circ\phi'=w\cdot (g\circ\phi)$$ up to homotopy relative to the basepoint.
Thus $$\phi'_f(1)=\hat{w}(\phi_f(1)),\qquad \phi'_g(1)=\hat{w}(\phi_g(1)),$$ where $\hat{w}$ is the covering action of $w$, mapping $(x,y)\mapsto (x+a\pi,y+ b\pi)$, for some fixed $a,b\in \mathbb{2Z}$.
Finally, we note that $$p(t\phi'_f(1)+(1-t)\phi'_g(1))\\=p(t(\phi_f(1)+(a\pi,b\pi))+(1-t)(\phi_g(1)+(a\pi,b\pi)))\\=
p(t\phi_f(1)+(1-t)\phi_g(1)+(a\pi,b\pi))\\=p(t\phi_f(1)+(1-t)\phi_g(1)),$$ as required.

